# Is it possible to use MSBuild Extension Pack without installation?

Tags: .net, msbuild

Is there a way to use the MSBuild Extension Pack with a "local" reference that doesn't require you to run the installer? In other words, can you store the targets in a solution items folder so that every developer doesn't have to install it?

Comment: The name for that kind of "installation" is called "xcopy deployment"

Comment: My last comment is a bit poor on grammar. Sorry, I'm sleepy...

Comment: I don't follow. I was wondering if you can reference the MSBuild Extensions at any location on the machine, without running the msi to install the Extensions.

Comment: @Bob: I understand your question (even though I can't answer it). I was just pointing that what you want is to "do xcopy deployment of the MSBuild Extension Pack". Just giving you the name for future reference.

Comment: You might want to evaluate NAnt as an alternative. http://nant.sourceforge.net/ - see also http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 20):

You have to declare the property, **ExtensionTasksPath**, before the import statment for the tasks. For example take a look at:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExtensionTasksPath Condition="'$(ExtensionTasksPath)' == ''">E:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\</ExtensionTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(ExtensionTasksPath)MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>

  <Target Name="Demo">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="GetTempFileName">
      <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="TempPath"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File>

    <Message Text="TempPath: $(TempPath)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The MSBuild Community tasks is similar but the property is named  **MSBuildCommunityTasksLib**. I think for SDC tasks its called **TasksPath**.

Comment: Thank you! I just watched your DNRtv episodes on MSBuild and they were fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble getting this to work with relative paths (ie not c:\blah but ..\blah).

This is because you couldn't re-use the ExtensionTasksPath variable if it was relative, since your file (.csproj) and the MsBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks file are in different locations, resulting in a different value for the relative path.

In the end this is what got it working for me (put at top of your .csproj file):

```
    <PropertyGroup>
   <ExtensionTasksPath Condition="'$(ExtensionTasksPath)' == ''">..\4.0\</ExtensionTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="..\references\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
```

The reason why you need the "..\4.0\" instead of just "" (blank) is because the MsBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks file detects blank and does some different stuff if that is the case. I didn't want to hack the MsBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks file in case I wanted to upgrade it later.