# How do I import the msbuildcommunitytasks project from another msbuild project with a relative file path?

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

Please go easy I am new to msbuild and msbuildtasks!

How can I set a property which represents a relative file path to a targets file which I want to import?  I need relative references so it will work on all dev machines.  But the target for import is trying to use the relative file path internally, which won't work as it is re-evaluated relative to the imported target!

Effectively I am trying to work around the [documented behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) of imported projects:

> All relative paths in imported
>   projects are interpreted relative to
>   the directory of the imported project.
>   Therefore, if a project file is
>   imported into several project files in
>   different locations, the relative
>   paths in the imported project file
>   will be interpreted differently for
>   each imported project.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't put the MSBuildCommunityTask lib side by side with MSBuild to %PROGDIR%\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\ ? The path could then be relative to MSBuild (like suggested by MSBCT people): <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

Comment: Yes, because I would then have to install it on all dev/build machines and then have to manage upgrading them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer. Essentially you have to set the property MSBuildCommunityTasksPath as a relative path back to the original containing directory.

For example, given a folder structure like this:

```
Root---project---Build---{My msbuild project}
           |
           |-Tools---MSBuildCommunityTasks---{Binaries and Targets}
```

Where : 
{My msbuild project} is in Root\Project\Build\
{MSbuildCommunityTasks} is in Root\Project\Tools\MsBuildCommunityTasks

To get the targets project to reference its binaries via the property MSBuildCommunityTasksPath, it will find the tasks file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>..\MSBuildCommunityTasks\</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath> <!--Relative path back to yourself-->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can import the targets file with another relative file reference :

```
  <Import Project="..\..\Tools\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MsBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
```

Answer (score 15):

There was a similar question at [Is it possible to use MSBuild Extension Pack without installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776962/msbuild-extension-pack). That question was how to do the same with the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack), both of which are similar in this aspect. For the Extension Pack you have to declare the property **ExtensionTasksPath**,and for the Community tasks you have to declare a similar property named **MSBuildCommunityTasksLib**. So in your case it should look like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksLib)' == ''">E:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\CommunityTasks\</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksLib)MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <Target Name="Demo">
    <!-- Use the tasks here -->
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: But these are absolute file paths no?  Or am I missunderstanding?  I need to reference it with a relative file path, or at least to be able to convert the relative file path at runtime.

Comment: Most of the tools require a full path to work properly. I've set up a couple of variables in a .proj that I incude in all of my 'working' .proj files. These variables contain the fixed part of paths for various things. 

   In a Property Group: <SolutionRoot>$(WorkingDrive)$(SolutionFolder)\$(Branch)\NET\BuildOut$(Configuration)</SolutionRoot> 

   $(SolutionFolder) is built from other things, like the Major-Minor build number etc. (Specific to our setup) 

   Then the other .proj files import it: 
   <Import Project="AlliantBuildProperties.proj"/>

Comment: You should be able to build a full path from relative path. You can use properties like MSBuildProjectDirectory.

Comment: "<MSBuildCommunityTasksLibCondition=" should be "<MSBuildCommunityTasksLib Condition="

Comment: Declaring MSBuildCommunityTasksLib  might not be enough, see @Vipresh 's answer

Answer (score 5):

@Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

Talkin about MSBuild4
Just declaring the MSBuildCommunityTasksLib wont suffice cause if u check the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets file the properties are declared as follows

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

So if U only over ride the MSBuildCommunityTasksLib it will again get over ridden in the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets file as it is not conditional
So u HAVE TO ALSO OVERRIDE MSBuildCommunityTasksPath so that its proerty is NOT SET FROM MSBuildExtensionsPath but from ur custom path.
Correst me if I m wrong

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be one answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/feb782e3-72ae-4476-9011-617796f217b6

But this (if I understand it correctly) appears to be a ridiculous solution.  To get the paths to work I need to change the *imported* project references?  What would happen if I wanted to reference the imported project from third project in another folder?!?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob at msbuild if I'm quite honest however I've just solved my own problem I had with this. I was turning one of the targets into its own project and it wasn't finding the paths for the msbuild community paths. If you look at your original project you may find something like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ExtensionTasksPath>./</ExtensionTasksPath>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>./</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="MSBuildExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
<Import Project="MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
```

Copy this code into your new project and it should work.

Comment: This cannot work. Your variables are not even escaped using $(). Example:
<Import project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add, since i cannot comment (rep), that to do a path to your particular project you can use $(SolutionDir) on your property group like so:

$(SolutionDir)\My Code\Community\MSBuild\CommunityTasks\

This way its not tied down to a specific drive and can be based off of the location of the project relative to your solutions directory structure.

Also thanks for the answer above it helped me in my project with the addition above.